# Is it possible in a where clause to compare against an array?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

For example

```
    foreach(var content in Model.Where(c=>c.Key != array))
```

Where array is

```
    string[] = new string[] {"KeyName1", "KeyName2", "KeyName3"};
```

This would be immensely helpful as I have almost 20 Keynames, and would like an easier way to manage them than using a long list of

```
c.Key != "KeyName1" && c.Key != "KeyName2"
```

This is a little bit more advanced usage than I'm used to so assistance would be helpful.

Comment: `Where(c => !keys.Contains(c.Key))`. Please read [ask] next time and share your research. :)

Comment: the other answer is not quite the same, `Model.Where(c=>! array.Contains(c.Key))`

Comment: I looked, but couldn't find any similar questions, apparently I was wording it wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foreach (var content in Model.Where(c => !array.Contains(c.Key)))`